# Netcat Error: nc forward host lookup failed h_errno 11001 host_not_found

Tags: connection, netcat

I'm using Netcat for Windows but I get this error when I try to open a connection:

```
nc forward host lookup failed h_errno 11001 host_not_found
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What arguments/options are you passing to `nc`?

Comment: @DNA: resolved, it was caused by firewall

Comment: and how u solved it ?